# How to load incremental records from Oracle to HDFS on daily basis and Can we use Sqoop or MR Jobs. Which is the preferred method

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

How to load incremental records from Oracle to HDFS on daily basis? Can we use Sqoop or MR Jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop is designed exactly for this purpose, and will result in MR jobs that do the work of copying data.  There are several methods of determining what is new in the Oracle table, for example using the table's id, or perhaps a date modified field if you have one.

Compared to most thing in Hadoop, Sqoop is pretty easy.  Here's a link to the doc -- search for "incremental" or start with section 7.2.9 for more info.  http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html

FYI Once you get this working normally, check out the Sqoop extension designed to work with Oracle database that uses a vey efficient method for streaming data directly, making the process even faster and lightweight on your Oracle DB.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanks Tom